# 1 output bindings in Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binder

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

in this [page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_summary_of_function_based_programming_styles_for_kafka_streams) tells that you can't make just one Outputs

but I need to make just one Outputs by using Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binder

what should I do?

some articles says that using org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge but it's not works for me

I made StreamBridge to send topics to Kafka but Kafka doesn't produce topics to my Spring boot application

and this is my application.yml and produce topic code

```
// producer Springboot application  



  spring.cloud.stream:
    kafka:
        binder:
            brokers: {AWS.IP}:9092
            zkNodes: {AWS.IP}:2181
    bindings:
        deliveryIncoming:
            destination : deliveryIncomingtopic

@Bean
public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
  // wanna produce deliveryIncomingtopic and send to Spring's Consumer
}
```

---

```
// Consumer Springboot application

spring : 
     cloud:
        stream:
            kafka:
                binder: 
                    brokers: {AWS.IP}:9092
                    zkNodes: {AWS.IP}:2181
            function:
                definition : deliveryIncoming;

            bindings:
                deliveryIncoming-in-0:
                    destination : deliveryIncomingtopic

    @Bean
    public Consumer<KStream<String, String>> deliveryIncoming() { 
        return input ->
                input.foreach((key, value) -> {
                    System.out.println("deliveryIncoming is playing");
                    System.out.println("Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
                }); 
    }
```

## EDIT

sorry I think I made kind of unclear

I just want to do like below

produce(deliveryIncomingtopic) -> Kafka -> consumer(deliveryIncomingtopic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's the case, then you need to change your bean function definition to return `java.util.Function` instead of `java.util.Consumer`.

```
@Bean
public Function<KStream<String, String>, KStream<String, String>> deliveryIncoming() {
return input ->
                input.foreach((key, value) -> {
                    System.out.println("deliveryIncoming is playing");
                    System.out.println("Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
                }); 
}
```

However, AFAIK.. you still need to define the output channel in your **application.yml**. You can use the same name with different suffix. Something like below :

```
deliveryIncoming-in-0:
   destination: <your_topic_name>
deliveryIncoming-out-0:
   destination: <your_topic_name>
```

Comment: thansk for ur answering but
as I mentioned  there're two application so Funtion is not what I want 
and Function can't make just only one out bound topics

Comment: Hi Yong. AFAIK, with Spring Cloud Stream, we can implement our binder either in an imperative way (by creating a binding interface and listener class that is annotated with @EnableBinding annotation), or in a functional way through Spring Cloud Function as what you've implemented here. Either ways, we still need to define our input and output channel separately as what i've shown here (even it's routed for the same destination topic, so it's still one topic actually). Spring Cloud Function will recognize whether it's an input or output based on their suffix.

Comment: Let's say you have two applications/services, One represents the producer while another one will be a consumer. In that case, at the producer side you can send a message using StreamBridge as you mentioned earlier, so more or less your service class will contain this line (to outbound your message): 

`streamBridge.send(deliveryIncoming-out-0, data);`

Comment: As for the consumer side, you can use that Consumer bean function (as you've written above) to represents the listener that will consume your message

Comment: And within your application.yml, you can have something like this : 

```
deliveryIncoming-in-0:
   destination: deliveryIncoming
deliveryIncoming-out-0:
   destination: deliveryIncoming
```

So it's still the same topic as You can see there. Just different suffix to distinguished between an input and output channel. 
Nonetheless, me personally never use this kind of approach. But I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to make things clear here. Are you looking to consume a message from your inbound topic `deliveryIncomingtopic` and then generate/produce another message to another output topic ?
If that's your question about, then I believe you were missing something there within your `application.yml`.
You need to have another configuration for your output topic. e.g. :

Since you're using Spring Cloud Function (based on what i see in your **application.yml**), then you should add more configuration for your output topic as follow:

```
spring : 
     cloud:
        stream:
            kafka:
                binder: 
                    brokers: {AWS.IP}:9092
                    zkNodes: {AWS.IP}:2181
            function:
                definition: deliveryIncoming;deliveryOutput

            bindings:
                deliveryIncoming-in-0:
                    destination: deliveryIncomingtopic
                deliveryOutput-out-0:
                    destination: deliveryOutput
```

And also define another bean for your producer function :

```
@Bean
public Producer<KStream<String, String>> deliveryOutput() { 
   // do your necessary logic here to outbound your message
}
```

Hope this will match your expectation.

Comment: sorry  I think my code's unclear
I just want to do like below
produce(deliveryIncomingtopic) -> Kafka -> consumer(deliveryIncomingtopic)